# How do I set it up so there is two different prices

Tags: javascript, html, function

How do I get my program to work so that it has the separate price for the gourmet pizzas and the regular pizzas? And then add them together with the calculate function.

So if I order 1 regular pizza and 1 gourmet it gives me the proper cost.

The regular pizzas are: Hawaiian, Cheese, Veggie, supreme, pepperoni,
the gourmet pizzas are: meat-lovers, chicken, prawn.

```
<html>
<title> Pete's Pizza </title>

<script>


//Menu: Hawaiian, Cheese, Veggie, supreme, pepperoni, meat-lovers, chicken, prawn.

//global variables
var totalNumber = 0;   // for total number of Pizzas ordered
var pizzaPrice = 9.50;   // price of each pizza
var pizzaPriceGourmet = 15.50;  //price for gourmet pizzas
var pizzaDelivery = 5;  //price for pizza delivery
var orderTotalPrice = 0;   // total cost of order


function order()
{
  var pizza = new Array()
  pizza[0] = document.form.hawaiian.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[0] = Number(pizza[0])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[1] = document.form.cheese.value                 //allocates type of pizza in array            
  pizza[1] = Number(pizza[1])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[2] = document.form.veggie.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[2] = Number(pizza[2])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[3] = document.form.supreme.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[3] = Number(pizza[3])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[4] = document.form.pepperoni.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[4] = Number(pizza[4])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[5] = document.form.meatlovers.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[5] = Number(pizza[5])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[6] = document.form.chicken.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[6] = Number(pizza[6])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[7] = document.form.prawn.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[7] = Number(pizza[7])                            //converts to number value

  totalNumber = pizza[0] + pizza[1] + pizza[2] + pizza[3] + pizza[4] + pizza[5] + pizza[6] + pizza [7];



 alert("You have ordered:" + "\n" +        
         "Hawaiian Pizza:" + pizza [0] + "\n" +
         "Cheese Pizza:" + pizza [1] + "\n" +
         "Veggie Pizza:" + pizza [2] + "\n" + 
         "Supreme Pizza:" + pizza [3] + "\n" +
         "Pepperoni Pizza:" + pizza [4] + "\n" +
         "Meat-Lovers Pizza:" + pizza [5] + "\n" +
         "Chicken Pizza:" + pizza [6] + "\n" +
         "Prawn Pizza:" + pizza [7]);   


if (totalNumber >12) {          // Limit for total amount of Pizzas ordered
    alert("There is a limit of 12 pizzas per order. Please cancel Order and re-order. Current total is:" +totalNumber);
    } else 
    alert("Total number of burgers ordered:" + totalNumber); //Total amount of pizzas ordered
    calculate()  //Begins calculation function
}


function calculate()    //Function for the cost of the order
{
    orderTotalPrice = (totalNumber*pizzaPrice + totalNumber*pizzaPriceGourmet);  //order total+ amount of pizzas ordered * pizza price
    alert("Total cost of pizzas is: $" + orderTotalPrice.toFixed(2) );  //Display order cost as "$"0.00
}
</script>
```

Comment: I smell a uni project ;)

Comment: no, it is a for fun project I started doing. To try and see how good I am at coding. apparently I'm not very good. But I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just one advice, put your JavaScript code in a separate `.js` file.

Comment: Well to give you a hint, you're trying to share `variables` aka `totalNumber` between functions. In `js` variables are closed scope. Basically this means they are all private and only available inside the function they are created in. Unless you pass them around or make them global. I would suggest for your *cough* fun project you would look up `Javascript Scope` this will help you a lot

Comment: Creating an array is pointless, you already have all the information you need in the form's [*elements* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements). Iterate over that to do the processing, include the price as a *data-* attribute, or indicate the standard or gourmet pizza based on a *class* value. The "cancel order" button can simply be a reset button (no script required).

Comment: So Jamie, I understand that. But how am I able to link the price of "gourmetPizzaPrice" to the 3 pizzas that are gourmet?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ragzjxL3/ General idea: you could have an array of available pizzas objects with names and prices. Generate html from array. Bind on form.submit and use input values to calculate whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need gourmet pizza price?

Set a price for all the pizzas individually.  Then get the total as how many from how many ordered X price.

Then add totals at the end to get price

Declare the variable outside the function to be used everywhere even if this mean declaring an empty function

Var pizza1;